# Using ZeroC Middleware

Tags: middleware, ice

I'm currently looking at various middleware solutions that will allow me to create applications in a variety of languages which are able to communicate amongst each other.

The ZeroC product suite seems ideal as it provides a language agnostic way of defining data and the services that operate on the data (via its Slice IDL) and provides support for all the mainstream languages. It also appears to offer a lot of other things we'd want, such as load balancing, grid computing and managed deployment.

However, my google-fu has let me down and I'm having trouble finding information from people who have used it to implements system. I'm looking for feedback from projects that use it, and what issues/successes they had. I'm also interested in feedback from projects that evaluated it and chose not to use it (and why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that is what the projects section of the ZeroC forum is for, although it looks a bit sparse.

- http://www.zeroc.com/forums/projects/